# Asynchronous ajax call within a loop doesn't work as expected

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I am developing an internal web based tool

In that I need of generating a sequence of ajax calls based on a array value. I made as synchronous before, If I done like that, then it blocks the browser, so I cant able to show a loading image while the ajax are going.

Hence I changed the calls as asynchronous, now what happens is the ajax calls are going at a strech, and the response is same is for all the calls as in UI, but if I check that in firebug the response is clear, and if I put some alert within the loop then it works fine.

I posted the code for further reference

```
// calling the function within loop
$.each(texts, function (tind, tval) {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        txtcmpare(tval, search_logo, ask_logo, option_logo);
                    },2000);
                });

//the function which calls ajax (txtcmpare)
function txtcmpare(actval, sl, al, ol) {
                var tch_locale = new Array();
                var tch_tempname = new Array();

                    if (actval != "==" && actval != "") {
                        avail = 0;
                        tparam = actval;

                        //respout = findloacle(param);
                       setTimeout(function () {
                            findloacle(tparam, function (y) {
                                // my operations
                                 });
                              },2000);
                           }
                         if I put some alert here, sometimes response are clear
                          }

//the ajax function
function findloacle(locparam,callback) {
                //var loc = new Array();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Services/Locale.asmx/ajaxresp",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ queryparam: locparam }),
                    dataType: "json",
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        //loc = result.d;
                        callback(data);

                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("error");
                    }

                });
                //return loc;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply closure inside loop:

```
$.each(texts, function (tind, tval) {
    (function (_tval) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            txtcmpare(_tval, search_logo, ask_logo, option_logo);
        }, 2000);
    }(tval));
});
```

Comment: to keep reference (value) of internal variable, otherwise the async call could use the last value, not the current one. But i'm not sure this could works in this case as i don't have checked enough code in detail and using timeout could be the problem here

Comment: I understand the general idea of closures ;) I just don't know why one would want to add one here. The only value you preserve is `locparam` and it is neither changed within the function nor used by a callback.

Comment: Updated answer, look more appropriate here even i don't know what are supposed to be here other variables

Comment: Variable scope is the problem - fixed

Comment: But the thing is its not in a order...Is there any way to make an asynchronous call as sequence means one by one ???

Comment: Sure you can, but i've hard time to understand your logic with your code specially the use of timeouts here and there...

Comment: Ya I removed that actually now, I added since to make delay for the calls, but now its working fine without timeout.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into a similar problem myself. I was running a series of ajax requests in a while loop. Some calls were not being made! It was killing me!! My conclusion was that my browser -- Google Chrome -- ignores "duplicate" requests.

Take a look at this pseudo code:

```
while (i < ajaxCallArray.length) {
    currentAjaxObject = ajaxCallArray[i];
    ajaxPost = $.post(currentAjaxObject.url, function(data) {
    //response data needs to go into a function such that each request gets its own "data" variable created.otherwise it just overwrites data!!
    processAjaxResponse(data, currentAjaxObject);
        },"json");
i++;
}
```

If `ajaxCallArray[0].url = "http://www.google.com"`, `ajaxCallArray[1].url = "http://www.google.com"`, and `ajaxCallArray[2].url = "http://www.google.com"` the browser will only actually make 1 call!!

You have to do something like `ajaxCallArray[0].url = "http://www.google.com?count=0"`, `ajaxCallArray[1].url = "http://www.google.com?count=0"`, and `ajaxCallArray[2].url = "http://www.google.com?count=0"` even if you dont use those url parameters, just put something to make them distinct. That way the browser will process all the calls, even if they are done instantly.

Hope this helps!!